# Spring Security 4.x: how to obtain login that has been used during failed authentication?

Tags: spring-security

When user tries to authentication with wrong login/password I want to redisplay login that was used.

In Spring Security 3.x the following code allows me to accomplish that:

```
<input type="text" th:value="${session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null ? session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal : ''}" name="login" value="" />
```

But after updating to Spring Security 4.0.1 it stop working:

```
[2015-05-20 23:15:49.648] boot - 56559 ERROR [qtp83824030-29] --- ErrorController: Exception 'org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException' occurred at page /account/auth
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "exceptionOccurred ? session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal : ''" (account/auth:82)
...
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "exceptionOccurred ? session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal : ''" (account/auth:82)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 59): Property or field 'authentication' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:227)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:56)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:139)
    ... 94 more
```

This is because `BadCredentialsException` now [doesn't have extra information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-deprecations-core-ae).

The question is: how to achieve the same behavior in Spring Security 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this as follows:

Went into my security-context.xml and added an authentication-failure-handler-ref attribute to the form-login element

```xml
<form-login login-page="/login"
    username-parameter="j_username"
    password-parameter="j_password"
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler" />
```

Then I went and created a bean for that within the security-context.xml as well

```xml
<beans:bean id="authFailureHandler" class="path.to.your.LoginController"></beans:bean>
```

Next, I made my LoginController extend SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler, added the onAuthenticationFailure method which sets the last username in the session and redirects to the login failed page, in which the controller method gets that username from the session and puts it on the model, then removes it from the session.

```java
public class LoginController extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "security/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        model.addAttribute("LAST_USERNAME", request.getSession().getAttribute("LAST_USERNAME"));
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("LAST_USERNAME");
        return "security/login";
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException{
        rq.getSession().setAttribute("LAST_USERNAME", rq.getParameter("j_username"));
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(rq, rs, "/loginfailed");
    }
}
```

Which gets sets in the view as follows

```html
<input id="username" type="text" name="j_username" class="input-block-level form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="<c:if test="${not empty error}"><c:out value="${LAST_USERNAME}"/></c:if>" /><br />
```